# My Drupal secondary menu is not showing up anywhere

Tags: drupal

I am using the Acquia Slate theme.

http://drupal.org/project/acquia_slate

I've setup my Secondary Menu to show up in "sidebar first" block.  What I'm assuming is that when I select something from my Primary Menu (which I renamed) that the secondary menu would show up.  This is not the case.  I do have the secondary menu turned on and I'm on the latest Drupal 6 release.

Have a look.  http://www.andyczerwonka.com.  Under the Software Development menu at the top, I have a secondary menu.  When I select that menu, the "sidebar first" block on the left is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the secondary menu display nested primary menu items, eg:

```
primary 1
  - secondary 1
  - secondary 2
primary 2
```

you need to set the secondary menu source to be the same menu as the primary source. This is done at admin/build/menu/settings

Additionally, you need to make sure that items you want as secondary nav items are properly nested under a primary menu item.

Comment: arghhh.. the menu is now coming up but it's always in the same place, right next to the breadcrumb.  It doesn't matter where which block it sits in.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that gotcha. The theme usually will output a secondary menu. You can turn this off under the theme settings at admin/build/theme. The other thing I just remembered is that the core secondary menu block won't actually output correctly the nested primary menu items. If you don't want to use the secondary menu the theme outputs, you should take a look at the menu block module (http://drupal.org/project/menu_block). This module allows you to create menu blocks and specify which level of nesting the menu should start on.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is one of the most confusing things to learn about Drupal.  The secondary links block acts much differently form the secondary links element that you have in your theme.

This video really helped me on this issue:  http://www.lullabot.com/node/444/play